# Why do Sqlalchemy Session.close not log "rollback"?

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy

```
# I've set echo=True when doing create_engine, so I can see all the sql stmt
# DBSession is ScopeSession(thread_local) and autocommit is False
session = DBSession() 
session.add(somemodel)
# 
try:
    session.flush()
    raise Exception()
    session.commit()
except SQLAlchemyError as e:
    session.rollback()
finally:
    session.close()
```

acording to the SQLAlchemy docs:

```
The close() method issues a expunge_all(), and releases any transactional/connection
resources. When connections are returned to the connection pool, transactional state is
rolled back as well.
```

I expect to see the log "rollback" when executing "session.close()"

Comment: Why? Transactions are not committed unless you explicitly tell the database to commit. Closing the database connection or starting a new transaction thus implicitly rolls back.

Comment: a transaction also implicitly begin, but I can see the log "begin"

Comment: I am talking about the database level, not the SQLAlchemy level. SQLAlchemy is starting the transaction explicitly there, ending any previous transactions.

Answer (score 6):

the rollback (or if configured, the commit) that occurs in the Pool is not currently participating in the logging that the Engine normally does for commit/rollback events.

ticket: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/2752 has been added.

Edit: Took a look at this, and I think this logging should still be part of the pool's logger, not the engine's, otherwise you get a lot of this:

```
sqlalchemy.Engine: COMMIT
sqlalchemy.Engine: ROLLBACK (via pool)
```

An application really shouldn't have to worry too much about the pool's rollback of things, because if you're using a `Session`, you really should be calling `commit()` or `rollback()` right before any `close()` operation.

the pool logging is turned on normally by `create_engine("url", echo_pool='debug')`, or setting up logging on the `sqlalchemy.pool` namespace.