# Does closing a SQLAlchemy ORM Session roll back uncommitted changes?

Tags: python, sql, transactions, sqlalchemy

For example, is there a difference between the following two?

```
session = Session() # Session is a session maker
try:
    # do some work
    session.commit()
except:
    session.rollback()
finally:
    session.close()
```

and

```
session = Session()
try:
    # do some work
    session.commit()
finally:
    session.close()
```

The latter is what I used to do, because I assumed closing the session before committing (in case of an error) had the same effect as rolling back. But I saw the first form [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008441/why-do-sqlalchemy-session-close-not-log-rollback

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Closing](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#closing) a session will implicitly roll back current transactional state:

> The `close()` method issues a `expunge_all()`, and [releases](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/glossary.html#term-releases) any transactional/connection resources. When connections are returned to the connection pool, transactional state is rolled back as well.

But I'd argue that the first form is still better, since [explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). The author of SQLAlchemy also [seems to reflect this sentiment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17013336/2681632).

Comment: Explicit is always better than Implicit :)

Comment: @DineshPundkar Explicit better than implicit should be analysed on a case by case basis. For instance, you might not find it preferable to specify all default arguments of a function every time you use it. Imagine how the print statement would look like if you do that?