# SQLAlchemy Cannot operate on a closed database error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have this proxy class for SQLAlchemy Session:

```
class MySqlSession(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sql_session = DBSession()

    def close(self):
        if self._closed:
            return
        self._closed = True
        self._session.rollback()
        self._session.close()

    def __del__(delf):
        self.close()
```

DBSession is created by

`DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=True, expire_on_commit=True)`

and I receive exception:
`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) Cannot operate on a closed database.` on `self._session.rollback()` line when __del__ is called, but all queries to object, which received from self._session before __del__ calling is success.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How are you using this? `__del__` is only called when your object's reference count is reduced to zero - so if `close` has been called somewhere prior to that, when the object is garbage collected, you're trying to close a closed connection...

Comment: Therefore i have check `if self._closed: return`.
I use proxy object such as:
```session = MySqlSession()
# some queries
session = None```

Comment: Or... don't implement a `__del__` and just let the session object clear itself up which'll involve checking the connection is closed and any pending transactions are cancelled...

Comment: But does it lead to the rollback itself withowt calling session.rollback() manually?

Comment: Why are you hiding the rollback in close to begin with? Closing a session [does implicitly rollback the transactional state of a connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802739/does-closing-a-sqlalchemy-orm-session-roll-back-uncommitted-changes/46803458#46803458), but you [should still explicitly rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008441/why-do-sqlalchemy-session-close-not-log-rollback/17013336#17013336) a session. A much better way would be to create a context manager for use in a with-statement. Also provide a [mcve].