# What to do with a SqlAlchemy session only used for reads?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, rollback

I have created a context manager to get a transactional session, following the instructions [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html):

```
@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

And it's working great. Now I'd like to do something like that but for sessions that I know are only used to fetch values from the database.

Instead of `session.commit()`, what would be the best thing to do with the session? Just `.rollback()` and that's it?

Comment: Why not just `session.close()`?

Comment: @benvc zzzeek has expressed that one should preferrably always explicitly either commit or rollback instead of just closing and trusting in the implicit rollback: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008441/why-do-sqlalchemy-session-close-not-log-rollback

Comment: @IljaEverilä - thanks for the reference. Makes sense from a bulletproofing perspective, here is another post that I found useful on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309834/should-i-commit-or-rollback-a-read-transaction